# Using multiple filter on multiple columns of numpy array - more efficient way?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, filter, generator

I have the following 2 arrays:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
                [5, 6, 7, 8], 
                [7, 5, 6, 3],
                [2, 4, 8, 9]]

 ids = np.array([6, 5, 7, 8])
```

Each row in the array `arr` describes a 4-digit id, there are no redundant ids - neither in their values nor their combination. So if `[1, 2, 3, 4]` exists, no other combination of these 4 digits can exist. This will be important in a sec.

The array `ids` contains a 4-digit id, however the order might not be correct. Now I need to go through each row of `arr` and look if this id exists. In this example `ids` fits to the 2nd row from the top of `arr`. So `arr[1,:]`.

My current solution creates a filter of each column to check if the values of `ids` exist in any of the 4 columns. After that I use these filters on `arr`. This seems way too complicated.

So I pretty much do this:

```
 filter_1 = np.in1d(arr[:, 0], ids)
 filter_2 = np.in1d(arr[:, 1], ids)
 filter_3 = np.in1d(arr[:, 2], ids)
 filter_4 = np.in1d(arr[:, 3], ids)

 result = arr[filter_1 & filter_2 & filter_3 & filter_4]
```

Does anyone know a simpler solution? Maybe using generators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.isin`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html) all across `arr` and `all`-reduce to get `result` -

```
In [15]: arr[np.isin(arr, ids).all(1)]
Out[15]: array([[5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Cheers, this is way more elegant.